# Error 415 Unsupported Media Type in uploading files

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs

I am aware that there is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025248/how-can-i-fix-415-unsupported-media-type-on-file-upload-in-angular-6), but it didn't solve the above error.

This is my PUT action in my API's Controller and this is working fine in `Swagger`:

```
[HttpPut("{id}/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(string id, IFormFile file)  
{
    // codes using id above are omitted, nothing to do with the error

    var path = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        "wwwroot",
        file.FileName
    );

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))  
    {  
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

And here are the codes in my Angular web page:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="setFile($event.target.files)"/>

<button (click)="save()"> Save </button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
forUpload: File = null;
@Input() someModel: SomeModel;

// setting of file
setFile(myFile: File){
    if (myFile === null){
      return;
    }
    this.forUpload = myFile[0];
}

// saving
save() {
    const addFileFnc = this.theService.addFile.bind(this.theService);
    addFileFnc(this.someModel, this.forUpload).subscribe(
        () => { this.ref.close(); },
        (e) => { console.log(e); }
    );
}
```

And, my **service** is:

```
addFile(someModel: SomeModel, myFile: File): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${api_url}/api/somemodels/${someModel.id}/upload`, {
        id: someModel.id,
        file: myFile
    });
}
```

I also used `FormData` to try the answer in the said question above, I appended my `forUpload` File to a `FormData` but unfortunately, same error. How can I fix this if I don't have any kind of setting in media types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code together with the previous answer almost got it. I'd rather not change the parameters in your controller but there's something to add, that is `FromForm` attribute. So this will be your new controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(string id, [FromForm] IFormFile file)  
{
    // codes here
}
```

I'd agree with previous answer to use `FormData`, but I'll spare your `setFile()` from any changes and just some addition for **typescript**:

```
forUpload: File = null;
@Input() someModel: SomeModel;

save() {

    const addFileFnc = this.theService.addFile.bind(this.theService);

    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("id", this.someModel.id);
    formdata.append("file", this.forUpload);

    addFileFnc(formdata).subscribe(
        () => { this.ref.close(); },
        (e) => { console.log(e); }
    );
}
```

Instead of appending the whole `someModel`, I only did your `someModel.id` since I noticed that it is the only thing you are using in your service, which will be changed into this:

```
addFile(formdata: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${api_url}/api/somemodels/${formdata.get("id")}/upload`, formdata);
}
```

Your `Error 400 Bad Request` (as what said [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911060/10763029)) is because `formdata` in the **service**, based on the previous answer that you are following, is sending a *JSONify* `formdata` instead of the `FormData` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I upload file in ASP.Net Core and Angular

In the angular side you will need to use FormData to submit

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("SomeProp ", "somestring");
formdata.append("Image ", myFile); // change your code accordingly here

return this.http.put(`${api_url}/api/somemodels/${someModel.id}/upload`, {
    formdata
});
```

In server side

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I use `FromForm` attribute

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SavePost([FromForm]PostViewModel viewModel)
```

Update:
Make sure you enalbe CORS support in your ASP.Net Core like this

Enabling CORS

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors();
      services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But after doing your suggestion, the error still persist. Is this have something to do with `File.type()`?

Comment: What do you mean File.type() ? Where did you get that

Comment: I didn't use it in my current code but I am just curious if I need to modify the mime type of the file. But I don't have any configuration in my codes that restricts any types.

Comment: I realized its not the same error, right now. After the Error 415, it went to CORS related error then fixed. Now it is currently returning Error 400. Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Yes, I'm done with CORS. I fixed it but error 400 Bad Request replaced CORS error.

Comment: I am doing everything you suggested, and if this may help, I am trying to upload a `.zip` file.